# Weird shadows appearance in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, shadows

When trying to add a shadow, it looks like a bug as instead of adding it to the object, the background "cracks" into different-shadow pieces. I use my PC for other design-related programs, and it never happened to me, so I am excluding graphic card issue. I use MacBook Pro Retina 2015. I also added a screenshot of what happens when trying to use shading. Hope you can help me here[image]

Comment: This is a bug with blender. Try restarting blender or opening a new 3d viewport.

Comment: Nothing is changed :( I tried everything